# Evaluar si una lista de enteros es triangular en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por medio de un script de python deseo evaluar si una lista es triangular, es decir si es creciente hasta cierto elemento, y a partir de ese elemento es decreciente. Por ejemplo, la lista [2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3] es
triangular, mientras que la lista [2, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 4, 3, 1] no lo es.

He aquí mi código de prueba:

```
def listaTriangular(listaEv):
    lista_final = []
    if (len(listaEv) - 1) != 0:
        for i in range(len(listaEv) ):
            if listaEv[i] > listaEv[i - 1]:
                return print("La lista crece")
            else:
                return print("La lista decrece")
```

Evidentemente la lógica del progra permite reccorrer la lista, pero no compara los elementos como pide la consigna, así que estoy pensando mal la solución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea básica es, como ya esbozas, ir comparando un item con el siguiente, pero la clave está en detectar el pico para cambiar el sentido de la comparación a partir de él. Por otro lado, si hay dos valores contiguos iguales invalidan el triángulo en principio y esto no lo tienes en cuenta en la idea que planteas. Por último, para comparar cada item con el siguiente debes partir desde el elemento con índice 1, no con el de la posición 0, esto hace que la primera comparación sea el primer elemento con el último (`lista[0] > lista[-1]`) y no el primero con el segundo: `range(1, len(listaEv))`.

Existen muchas formas de hacer esto, por ejemplo:

```
def es_triangular(lista):
    # Si la lista tiene menos de 3 elementos no puede ser triangular
    if len(lista) < 3:
        return False

    # Iterador sobre la lista
    list_iter = iter(lista)

    # Usar los dos primeros elementos para determinar si es ascendente o descendente
    prim, ultimo = next(list_iter), next(list_iter)
    if prim < ultimo:
        ascendente = True
    elif prim > ultimo:
        ascendente = False
    else:
        return False

    pico = False
    for n in list_iter:
        if n == ultimo:
            return False
        elif not pico:
            if (ascendente and n < ultimo) or (not ascendente and n > ultimo):
                pico = True
        else:
            if (ascendente and n > ultimo) or (not ascendente and n < ultimo):
                return False
        ultimo = n

    # Retornamos True si hay pico, False en caso contrario
    return True if pico else False
```

Algunas características de esta aproximación, posiblemente mejorable son:

- Es considerablemente eficiente en términos de tiempo de ejecución, solo se itera una única vez sobre la lista completa en el peor de los casos. En el momento que se produce una incongruencia, la función retorna `False` y corta la iteración en ese punto. Por ejemplo, en la lista `[1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6]` el ciclo `for` realiza una única iteración.
- El uso de memoria es insignificante e independiente de la longitud de la lista. Se usa un iterador para recorrer la lista y aparte de éste no se crea ningún objeto más, las variables usadas se limitan a apuntar a referencias de objetos ya existentes.
- Valida tanto listas triangulares ascendentes como descendentes. Si solo se quisieran validar listas ascendentes la función se puede simplificar bastante.

Se puede usar indexado en vez de un iterador, pero es ligeramente más ineficiente. No obstante, solo hay que modificar un par de líneas:

```
def es_triangular(lista):
    if len(lista) < 3:
        return False

    prim, ultimo = lista[0], lista[1]
    if prim < ultimo:
        ascendente = True
    elif prim > ultimo:
        ascendente = False
    else:
        return False

    pico = False
    for i in range(2, len(lista)):
        n = lista[i]
        if n == ultimo:
            return False
        elif not pico:
            if (ascendente and n < ultimo) or (not ascendente and n > ultimo):
                pico = True
        else:
            if (ascendente and n >= ultimo) or (not ascendente and n <= ultimo):
                return False
        ultimo = n

    return True if pico else False
```

Algunos tests:

```
print(es_triangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3]))          # Triangular ascendente
print(es_triangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 4, 3, 1])) # No triangular
print(es_triangular([7, 6, 5, 4]))                # No triangular
print(es_triangular([8, 6, 5, 1, 7, 9]))          # Triangular descendente
print(es_triangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3]))          # Triangular ascendente
print(es_triangular([2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))          # No Triangular
print(es_triangular([6, 7, 6]))                   # Triangular ascendente
print(es_triangular([2, 4, 5]))                   # No triangular
print(es_triangular([8, 4, 7]))                   # Triangular descendente
print(es_triangular([2, 3]))                      # No triangular
print(es_triangular([2, 5, 5, 7, 4, 3]))          # No triangular
print(es_triangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3]))          # No triangular
print(es_triangular([2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 3]))          # No triangular
```

**Edición**

La linea del return usa la sintaxis del "operador ternario", sería equivalente a:

```
if pico:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

El `else` en realidad no es necesario dado que el return ocasiona que termine la ejecución:

```
if pico:
    return True
return False
```

Comment: ¿La última línea del return se puede escribir de forma más entendible?

Comment: Lo de "entendible" es relativo :), se puede usar un bloque if "normal". He editado la respuesta, mira al final.

Answer (score 1):

Esta función te dice si una lista es triangular, pero solo de forma ascendente. 
No se si será la forma más "pytónica" de hacerlo, pero se me ocurrió partir la lista por el valor máximo. Primero compara la lista desde el inicio hasta el numero mayor (lista1), con la misma lista1 ordenada ascendentemente, si es igual entonces pasa a la siguiente comparación. Luego compara que la lista desde el primer elemento descendente hasta el último (lista2) sea igual que la misma lista2 ordenada descendentemente. Si también cumple, entonces es triangular.

```
def listaTriangular(listaEv):
    max_elem_idx = listaEv.index(max(listaEv))
    lista1 = listaEv[0 : max_elem_idx+1]
    lista2 = listaEv[max_elem_idx+1 : ]
    message = "La lista no es triangular"
    if (len(lista1) > 1) and (lista1 == sorted(lista1)):
        if (len(lista2) != 0) and (lista2 == sorted(lista2, reverse=True)):
            message = "La Lista es triangular"
    return message

print(listaTriangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3]))
print(listaTriangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 4, 3, 1]))
print(listaTriangular([1, 2]))
print(listaTriangular([1, 2, 3]))
print(listaTriangular([3, 2, 1]))
print(listaTriangular([2, 3, 1]))
print(listaTriangular([1]))
```

Salida:

```
La Lista es triangular
La lista no es triangular
La lista no es triangular
La lista no es triangular
La lista no es triangular
La Lista es triangular
La lista no es triangular
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar:

```
for i in range(len(listaEv) ):
    if listaEv[i] > listaEv[i - 1]:
       return print("La lista crece")
    else:
       return print("La lista decrece")
```

La verificación que haces dentro del `for` solo se verifica una vez, ya que cualquiera sea el resultado, sales de la función con un `return` y por otro lado, en python, cuando haces `listaEv[i - 1]` e `i = 0` terminas con `listaEv[-1]` que es totalmente válido, solo que representa el último elemento y no creo que eso sea lo que estás buscando.

Creo que la idea la tienes: verificar la existencia dentro de la lista de un patrón de crecimiento y luego de un patrón de decremento o viceversa, no importa la longitud de cada patrón, lo que sí, solo deben existir dos patrones únicos, si primero crece, luego decrece y vuelve a crecer tenemos tres patrones distintos y eso inválida el requerimiento, o incluso si solo tenemos un patrón estaríamos en la misma situación.

En la práctica tendremos tres patrones en cualquier lista, o crece (+1) o decrece (-1) o se mantiene igual (0), lo que nos interesa es que solo existan dos patrones (+1) y (-1).

Para detectar los patrones, podemos hacer algo así:

```
def patrones(lista):
  return [1 if lista[i] > lista[i-1] else -1 if lista[i] < lista[i-1] else 0 for i in range(1,len(lista))]

print(patrones([2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3]))
print(patrones([1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6]))
print(patrones([7, 5, 3]))
print(patrones([1, 2]))

[1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
[1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1]
[1]
```

la función `patrones` retorna los patrones mencionados, simplemente usa una comprensión de listas para ir comparando cada elemento de la lista con el anterior, la particularidad es que debemos empezar a comparar desde el segundo elemento de ahí que hagamos `range(1,len(lista))` la verificación no es compleja, simplemente `1 if lista[i] > lista[i-1] else -1 if lista[i] < lista[i-1] else 0`, es decir obtendremos un +1 si la lista crece, un -1 si decrece y un 0 si se mantiene con el mismo valor.

La salida nos da una idea de cual de las listas es efectivamente es una lista triangular, únicamente el primer caso lo es, como decíamos, solo tenemos dos patrones y estos son +1 y -1. El segundo caso tenemos efectivamente los patrones +1 y -1, pero tenemos tres patrones, con lo cual tampoco es una lista triangular.

Teniendo el patrón construido, es fácil verificar los requerimientos:

```
from itertools import groupby

def patrones(lista):
      return [1 if lista[i] > lista[i-1] else -1 if lista[i] < lista[i-1] else 0 for i in range(1,len(lista))]

def listaTriangular(lista):
  p = [e[0] for e in list(groupby(patrones(lista)))]
  return len(p) == 2 and (p == [-1,1] or p == [1,-1])


print(listaTriangular([1]))
print(listaTriangular([1,2,3]))
print(listaTriangular([1,1,1]))
print(listaTriangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3]))
print(listaTriangular([2, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 4, 3, 1]))

False
False
False
True
False
```

Usamos `groupby()` del módulo `itertools` para obtener los grupos, la única posibilidad que no sirve es que sean 2 y sean `[-1,1]` o  `[1,-1]`